# geometric series diagram query.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, exponential-function, geometric-progressions, proof-without-words

I was going through this article on geometric series on Wikipedia and found this diagrammatic representation of an infinite geometric series with a said common factor of (1/2) but shouldn't the common factor be (1/4) based on the diagram? 
link to the diagram:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:GeometricSquares.svg#/media/File:GeometricSquares.svg

Answer (score 1):

The series in the introduction of the article [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and the sequence depicted in your diagram are not the same. The one in the introduction is $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}$ while the one in the diagram is $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n}$.

So, yes, the common factor is $\frac{1}{4}$ as you say.

Comment: So is the series within the diagram proportional to the shaded area?

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but then that's what the author says: the first term of the series is $\frac12\times\frac12=\frac14$, the second one is $\frac14\times\frac14=\frac1{16}$, and so on. And its sum is$$\frac{1/4}{1-1/4}=\frac{1/4}{3/4}=\frac13.$$

Comment: But the series within the diagram goes like - 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 and so on...what am I missing?

Comment: Those are the *sides* of the squares. The series is the series of their *areas*, which is$$\frac14+\frac1{4^2}+\frac1{4^3}+\cdots$$

Comment: oh, thank you so much